# BlocBuilder isn't building my Widgets every time I emit a new state

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, cubit

I'm studying Bloc and Cubit state manegement with a Tic Tac Toe game and I'm not being able to render the Board after a new player select a tile.  Why BlocBuilder isn't building everytime I emit a new state?

Here is my GameCubit:

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import 'game_state.dart';

class GameCubit extends Cubit<GameState> {
  GameCubit({
    GameState? initialState,
  }) : super(initialState ?? const GameState());

  void makePlay({required int index, required String playerTurn}) {
    if (state.board[index] != '') return;

    List<String> actualBoard = List.from(state.board);
    actualBoard[index] = playerTurn;

    if (_hasWinner()) {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          status: GameStatus.hasWinner,
          gameWinner: playerTurn,
          playerTurn: revertPlayerTurn(actualPlayer: playerTurn),
        ),
      );
      resetBoard();
    } else if (_hasDraw()) {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          status: GameStatus.hasDraw,
        ),
      );

      resetBoard();
    } else {
      return emit(
        state.copyWith(
          playerTurn: revertPlayerTurn(actualPlayer: playerTurn),
          status: GameStatus.inProgress,
          board: actualBoard,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  String revertPlayerTurn({required String actualPlayer}) =>
      actualPlayer == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';

  void resetBoard() => emit(
        state.copyWith(
          board: List.filled(9, '', growable: false),
          status: GameStatus.initial,
        ),
      );

  bool _hasWinner() {
    if (state.board[0] != '' &&
            state.board[0] == state.board[1] &&
            state.board[0] == state.board[2] ||
        state.board[3] != '' &&
            state.board[3] == state.board[4] &&
            state.board[3] == state.board[5] ||
        state.board[6] != '' &&
            state.board[6] == state.board[7] &&
            state.board[6] == state.board[8] ||
        state.board[0] != '' &&
            state.board[0] == state.board[4] &&
            state.board[0] == state.board[8] ||
        state.board[2] != '' &&
            state.board[2] == state.board[6] &&
            state.board[2] == state.board[4] ||
        state.board[0] != '' &&
            state.board[0] == state.board[3] &&
            state.board[0] == state.board[6] ||
        state.board[1] != '' &&
            state.board[1] == state.board[4] &&
            state.board[1] == state.board[7] ||
        state.board[2] != '' &&
            state.board[2] == state.board[5] &&
            state.board[2] == state.board[8]) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  void increaseWinScore({required String winner}) {
    if (winner == 'X') {
      return emit(state.copyWith(xPlayerScore: state.xPlayerScore + 1));
    } else {
      return emit(state.copyWith(xPlayerScore: state.oPlayerScore + 1));
    }
  }

  void increaseDrawScore() => emit(
        state.copyWith(
          drawGameScore: state.drawGameScore + 1,
        ),
      );

  void resetScore() => emit(
        state.copyWith(
            xPlayerScore: 0,
            oPlayerScore: 0,
            drawGameScore: 0,
            status: GameStatus.initial),
      );

  bool _hasDraw() => !state.board.contains('');
}
```

Here is my GameState:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

enum GameStatus { initial, inProgress, hasWinner, hasDraw, error }

class GameState extends Equatable {
  const GameState({
    this.status = GameStatus.initial,
    this.playerTurn = 'X',
    this.drawGameScore = 0,
    this.oPlayerScore = 0,
    this.xPlayerScore = 0,
    this.board = const ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    this.gameWinner,
  });

  final GameStatus status;
  final String playerTurn;
  final int drawGameScore;
  final int oPlayerScore;
  final int xPlayerScore;
  final List<String> board;
  final String? gameWinner;

  GameState copyWith({
    GameStatus? status,
    String? playerTurn,
    int? drawGameScore,
    int? oPlayerScore,
    int? xPlayerScore,
    String? gameWinner,
    List<String>? board,
  }) {
    return GameState(
      status: status ?? this.status,
      playerTurn: playerTurn ?? this.playerTurn,
      gameWinner: gameWinner ?? this.gameWinner,
      drawGameScore: drawGameScore ?? this.drawGameScore,
      xPlayerScore: xPlayerScore ?? this.xPlayerScore,
      oPlayerScore: oPlayerScore ?? this.oPlayerScore,
      board: board ?? this.board,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => <Object?>[];
}
```

And here is my Game screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

import '../theme/colors.dart';
import '../bloc/game_cubit.dart';
import '../bloc/game_state.dart';

class Game extends StatelessWidget {
  const Game({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  void _showWinDialog({
    required BuildContext context,
    required GameCubit cubit,
    required String winner,
  }) {
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(' $winner  venceu!'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: const Text("Jogar novamente"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _showDrawDialog({
    required BuildContext context,
    required GameCubit cubit,
  }) {
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Empate!'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: const Text("Jogar novamente"),
              onPressed: () {
                cubit.resetBoard();
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cubit = context.read<GameCubit>();

    return BlocConsumer<GameCubit, GameState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state.status == GameStatus.hasWinner && state.gameWinner != null) {
          _showWinDialog(
            context: context,
            cubit: cubit,
            winner: state.gameWinner!,
          );
        }

        if (state.status == GameStatus.hasDraw) {
          _showDrawDialog(
            context: context,
            cubit: cubit,
          );
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: CoreColors.primaryColor,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(title),
            backgroundColor: CoreColors.primaryColor,
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 60),
                child: GridView.count(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                  children: List.generate(
                    9,
                    (index) => InkWell(
                      onTap: () => cubit.makePlay(
                        index: index,
                        playerTurn: state.playerTurn,
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 8,
                        width: 8,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(13),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            state.board[index],
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 70,
                              color: CoreColors.primaryColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'Agora é a vez do ${state.playerTurn} de jogar',
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text('X venceu ${state.xPlayerScore} vez(es)'),
                  Text('O venceu ${state.oPlayerScore} vez(es)'),
                  Text('Empatou ${state.drawGameScore} vez(es)'),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
            onPressed: () {
              cubit.resetBoard();
              cubit.resetScore();
            },
            label: const Text(
              'Reset',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.replay_circle_filled, color: Colors.white),
            backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried with BlocConsumer too. But the builder method isn't being called even if the cubit.makePlay (the method that emit a new state) is called.

Comment: I didn't go through the code, but I know that two adjacent events that are "equal" are de-duped.  Is there a chance you're generating equal events?

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! But I've checked this. Every emit has a property change. There's no way to emit the same props

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I forgot to override the getters to all the props. So the Equatable wasn't able to identify that the GameState had changes.

I only edited this in my GameState and worked as expected:

```
@override
  List<Object?> get props => <Object?>[
        status,
        playerTurn,
        drawGameScore,
        oPlayerScore,
        xPlayerScore,
        gameWinner,
        board,
      ];
```